# Why is my tag closing early for the section tag?

Tags: html, angular

I am getting an error and says the 'section' is closed by another tag.

I checked my HTML and everything looks good.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="display$ | async as display">
    <section [class.open]="display === 'open'" (click)="close()">
             <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                <button class="close" type="button" (click)="close()">X</button>
    
    <div class="dateAlignment">
        <div class="dateComponent">
            <div class="date-selection">        
                <div class="month">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedMonth"   list="correctionMonth" placeholder="Month...." >
                    <datalist id="correctionMonth">
                        <option value="{{item.Name}}" [selected]="item.isSelected" *ngFor="let item of selectedMonthArray">{{item.id}}</option>
                    </datalist>
                </div>
                <div class="year">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear"  list="correctionYear" placeholder="Year...." >
                    <datalist id="correctionYear">
                        <option value="{{item}}" *ngFor="let item of yearArray">{{item}}</option>
                    </datalist>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="buttongroup">
                <div class="submit">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary reportButton">Correction Notices</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary reportButton">Display Tablular Data</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary reportButton">Mailing Labels</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submitgroup">
                <div class="reportApplication">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Apply</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>    
</ng-container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your `div` tags is unclosed. Maybe you meant to enclose the `<button>` tag in a div?

```
<section [class.open]="display === 'open'" (click)="close()">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          <button class="close" type="button" (click)="close()">X</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: My code wasn't formatted properly here but I checked in VS Code and every tag has an opening and closing tag (except input since they are self-closing). Angular complains that it has been closed by another tag and if I remove my content and open and close the <section>. it still complains

Answer (score 1):

on the line 9, where you have the input. the input is a self-closing tag. it should be closed as below:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="selectedYear"  list="correctionYear" placeholder="Year...." />
```

this is a self closing tag.  you missed the **/**

let me know if it works

Comment: Only if he's using a time machine to go back to 1999 and write XHTML... `<input>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element) in HTML5 and does not require a closing tag, adding one will actually make it invalid. If you self-close an empty element the closing slash will simply be ignored by most parsers.

Comment: funny comment but true. input elements don't require a close tag. They are self-closing. However I did try it and it didn't resolve the issue